# What is fn.bind.apply(fn, arguments) doing?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I saw this shortcut given as an answer on a code Kata but I am having difficulty understanding exactly what the below example is doing.

```
function func(fn) {
  return fn.bind.apply(fn, arguments);
}
```

So far my understanding is that bind creates a new function similar to doing the following:

```
function func(fn) {
  return function () {
    return fn.apply(fn, arguments);
  };
}
```

Is this the case? Any clearer answers or breakdowns of what is going on would be great.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fn.bind
```

is just

```
Function.prototype.bind
```

So we're [applying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to `fn`, returning

```
fn.bind(arguments[0]/* doesn't matter, it's fn*/, arguments[1], arguments[2], etc.)
```

So the bound function is called with arguments being the arguments of `func` after `fn`.

Another way to write it would have been:

```
function func(fn) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function () {
    var localArgs = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return fn.apply(fn, args.concat(localArgs)); 
  };
}
```

The fact that the context of the call is the initial function (`arguments[0]`) is most certainly only a side effect. The important thing is we wrap the arguments with the function, but make it possible to dynamically pass other arguments.

**Example 1, wrapping all arguments :**

```
function add(a,b){
  return a+b
}
var f = func(add, 2 ,3); // f is a function which will always apply add to 2 and 3 
console.log(f()) // logs 5
```

**Exemple 2, [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):**

```
function multiply(a,b){
  return a*b
}
var multBy2  = func(multiply, 2);
console.log(multBy2(3)) // logs 6
```

Comment: Before 'Another way to write' is what helped me. Afterwards is extra credit. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I cannot upvote but you offered exactly the clarification I was hoping for.

Comment: So the body of `func` in the original code sample could be written as `return Function.prototype.bind.apply(fn, arguments);` and still work exactly the same? And the way it is written originally, the initial `fn` is basically meaningless?